# MPI non-blocking send and recv and mpi_iprobe() for unknown message size

Tags: mpi, deadlock

In a spatially decomposed 2D domain, I need to send particles to the 8 neighbors. I know how many I'm sending but not how many I'll receive from these neighbors.
I had implemented a code with MPI_Send(), MPI_Probe() and MPI_Recv() but I realized that it caused deadlocks whenever the message was too big.

I decided to go for non-blocking communications but then I can't figure out in what order  MPI_Isend, MPI_Irecv and MPI_Iprobe should be called? I definitely need to know the size my receiving buffer should be allocated to before actually calling MPI_Irecv so I'm tempted by the order MPI_Isend() then MPI_Iprobe() then MPI_Irecv(), but the problem is that MPI_Iprove() always returns a flag equal to false and I get stuck in the while loop. As far as I understand there no obligation for MPI to actually complete the send before the call to MPI_Wait(), therefore I understand that MPI_Iprobe might never return true. But if so, how does one receives an unknown size message in non-blocking MPI point-to-point communications?

Comment: that's right, thanks! I've tested with MPI_Probe and MPI_Recv and it works well. I'm not quite sure I understand why MPI_Probe does not block however. When is the message sent, what happens exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate answer/comment. The new SE ios app isn't totally clear on answers vs. comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make all 3 operations non-blocking. You can use an MPI_ISEND with a regular MPI_PROBE and/or MPI_RECV. It sounds like that might be a better option for you.

Comment: To answer your comment on the question, MPI_PROBE does block until it matches a message. MOI_IPROBE does not block (hence the 'I').